# Predict[] Application Timing

Tags: performance-tuning, machine-learning

I trained a `Predict` and when I look at `PredictorInformation` it says evaluation time is less than 1 millisecond per example. However, when I apply my `p` to a new input example, it takes almost 4 seconds. I want to apply it to almost 10,000 new examples so this is rather slow. Is there a way to apply it faster?

Edit:

Sharing the code is tricky, but a minimal example is:

```
DATA = Table[ Table[RandomReal[],{1000}] -> RandomReal[] ,{20000}];

p=Predict[DATA,Method->{"GradientBoostedTrees","MaxDepth"->8,"L1Regularization"->0.001}]
```

Of course the real data is not random, but it is read in from a file. It is all numbers.

Training is rather fast (10 minutes?) and when I look at the `PredictorInformation` it says about 1 millisecond per example. However, if I try to apply `p` to new data is is very slow.

Comment: Would you please share the code you used in copyable form? It is certainly hard to say anything useful without it...

Comment: Hi-- I added some code. the real data is from a csv file but I made some fake data.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it cannot be answered without additional information and OP has abandoned the post.

Answer (score 4):

The `PredictorFunction` `p` is treated by Mathematica as a function with attribute `Listable`. Exploiting this makes it 30 times faster for the presented example:

```
n = 20000;
m = 1000;
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, m}] -> RandomReal[{0, 1}, n];
p = Predict[data,
   Method -> {"GradientBoostedTrees", "MaxDepth" -> 8, 
     "L1Regularization" -> 0.001}
   ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.216127

Now, let's apply the predictor `p` to 1000 elements.

```
a = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {1000, m}];
b = p[a]; // RepeatedTiming // First
c = p /@ a; // RepeatedTiming // First
b == c
```

> 0.11
>
> 3.74
>
> True

The result of `PredictorInformation[p]` states 3.77 ms per evaluation. That's pretty close to the timing of `p /@ a`. The listable variant needs only 0.11 ms per evaluation.

Comment: Hm-- I tried this with just 5 of my 10,000 examples and it took 16 seconds. I was this is much longer then the milliseconds that the `PredictorInformation` showed. Also-- sorry, can't upvote! need 15 reputation.

Comment: What are the 10000 examples? What does ``Developer`PackedArrayQ[examles]`` return?

Comment: And how are you running the timing? It might also be a front-end issue and the kernel might still be fast.